# nothing happens on click

Tags: html, angular

```
const link = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="redirectToPage(store)" class="btn grey">' + displayText + '</a>';
```

When I am clicking on the button in the page than nothing happens. Where am I getting wrong? I am using angular 7.

```
redirectToPage(store){
alert('take me to store');
}
```

Comment: How do you use this param in html? <div [innerHTML]="link"></div> can work for you

Comment: can you post your template where you use the variable?

Comment: Modified the answer, Please check again

Comment: Angular transpile to javaScript changing the name of the "functions", so you can not do it using this aproach. You can use renderer2

Comment: Some interesting solution can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48817261/click-event-not-work-in-innerhtml-string-angular-4/48817568). But maybe you should ask why your html is inside a string (there's some design problem here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

`import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';`

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

    Window["AppComponent"] = this;
    this.link = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="Window.AppComponent.redirectToPage(`store`)" class="btn grey">' + this.displayText + '</a>');
  }

  displayText:any = "ABC"
  link 

  redirectToPage(store) {
    alert('take me to store');
  }
}
```

See [Stackbiltz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vj92yx)

Comment: didn't work for me.

Comment: Modified the answer, Please check again