# Adding click event to dynamically generated html

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm building an ionic app that lets users chat between each other.

In the event of a user sending a url as plain text, I have a function called `urlify` that replaces the text with html, and when a user clicks on the html for the url it should take them to that url.

The problem is, anchor elements don't open urls in Ionic, so I have to use `window.open(url)`..

Here is my code:

```
urlify(text) {
  if(text) {
    var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
        return '<span class="message-link">' + url + '</span>';
    })
  }
}

openLink(url) {
  window.open(url, '_system')
}
```

So when a user clicks the `span` it should open `openURL` but since I can't add `(click)="openURL(url)"` to the dynamically generated html, I'm not sure what to do..

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: @ABOS because it's user generated text so if someone adds a url as plain text eg https://google.com I need to convert it to a hyperlink so that it's clickable

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48028676/compile-dynamic-html-in-angular-4-5-something-similar-to-compile-in-angular-js

Answer (score 0):

This can help you, you can add anything dynamically on this way.

```
urlify(text) {
  if(text) {
    var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
        let newElement = document.createElement('span');
        newElement.innerHTML = url
        newElement.classList.add('message-link');
        newElement.onclick = function() {
            window.open(url, '_system')
        }
        return newElement
    });
  }
}
```

You can return this newElement or append it here, for example `document.getElementById('someDivID').append(newElement)` on this way