# Registering property changes of an object from another object

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns, es6-proxy

In my project, I have a `widgetBar` that can contain one or more `widget`s.

When clicking on the widget icon in the widgetBar, a panel is opened to show the conent of the pressed widget (kind of a navigation bar with all dropdown menus).

Each `widget` is a class that has a `togglePanel()` method that is bind to an onlcick event on the widget's icon and openes/closes the panel. This method also sets the widget's `isActive` property to either `true` (when panel opens), or `false` (when panel closes).

```
class Widget {
    isActive: boolean = false;
    element: HTMLElement;
    id: string;

    constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.element = document.crateElement('DIV');
        // ... this.element and other things represent the widget DOM object
        this.element.onclick = this.togglePanel.bind(this);
    }

    togglePanel() {
        if (this.panel.classList.contains('active')) {
            this.openPanel();
            this.isActive = true;
        } else {
            this.closePanel();
            this.isActive = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The `WidgetBar` constructor takes a list of `widget`s as argument that becomes its `this.widgets` property. It also has a `getWidgets()` methos that gives access to this property.

```
class WidgetBar {
    private widgets: Widget[];

    constructor(widgets: Widget[]) {
        this.widgets = widgets;
    }

    getWidgets() {
        return this.widgets;
    }
}
```

The (my project's) rule is that whenever a widget opens its panel, all the other panels should be closed.

How may I automatically check from the `WidgetBar` if one of its `widget`s has changed its `isActive` property so that I can make sure no more than one panel at a time is opened?

I read about [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), but I am not sure this is what could help me solving this problem.

### EDIT

What about [`Observable`s](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable)?

Would it be a good idea to make `isActive` property of the `Widget` class an Observable, and subscribe from `WidgetBar` to listen for any update, like explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46132784/1979665)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a bit tricky for me, but finally I used [`rxjs Subjects`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/subject) to solve my issue.

What I did was to create a new property `this.widgetActivated$ = new Subject();` which I populate calling `.next()` with an object like `{id: currentWidget.id, isActive: currentWidget.isActive}` whenever a widget panel is opened. Then I subscribe to it and call `closePanel()` on the other widgets which are active and have a different id.

This is the updated code:

```
interface widgetStatus {
    id: string;
    isActive: boolean;
}

class WidgetBar {
    private widgets: Widget[];
    private widgetActivated$: Subject<widgetStatus>; // IMPORTANT CHANGE

    constructor(widgets: Widget[]) {
        this.widgetActivated$ = new Subject(); // IMPORTANT CHANGE
        this.widgets = widgets;
    }

    getWidgets() {
        return this.widgets;
    }

    private widgetHandler(widget: Widget) {
        fromEvent(widget.widgetBox, 'click').subscribe(
            () => this.toggleWidgetPanel(widget)
        );
        this.widgetActivated$.subscribe(status => {
            const widgetsToClose = this.getWidgets().filter(widget => 
                widget.isActive === true && widget.id !== status.id);
            if (widgetsToClose) {
                widgetsToClose.forEach(widgetToClose => this.closePanel(widgetToClose));
            }
        })
    }

    private toggleWidgetPanel(widget: Widget) {
        if (!widget.getPanel().classList.contains("active")) {
            this.openPanel(widget);
        } else {
            this.closePanel(widget);
        }
    }

    private openPanel(widget: Widget) {
        widget.getPanel().classList.add("active");
        widget.isActive = true;
        this.widgetActivated$.next(this.getWidgetStatus(widget)); // IMPORTANT CHANGE
    }

    private closePanel(widget: Widget) {
        widget.getPanel().classList.remove("active");
    }

    private getWidgetStatus(widget: Widget): widgetStatus {
        return {id: widget.id, isActive: widget.isActive};
    }

}
```

I also converted `this.element.onclick = this.togglePanel.bind(this);` to be `fromEvent(widget.widgetBox, 'click').subscribe(() => this.toggleWidgetPanel(widget));` as I felt it is more readable and it didn't bring lot of issues about `thisArg` context (see [this other question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62956430/1979665)).

Answer (score 0):

You could have the widgets [emit an event](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) when they are opened. The widget bar's job would be to enforce the "rule". When it gets a new open event, you could have it call close on all the other child widgets(via ViewChild/ViewChildren).

Alternatively, you could move the logic out of the components and have a service that is in charge of all the logic. The service could expose the widgets and their properties (e.g. active) to the widget bar via an rxjs subscrib-able.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not using Angular. Anyway, I know Angular a bit and tried t replicate some of its goodness with only JS (and TypeScript above it). Any other idea?

Comment: whoops, sorry about that. How are you binding to the dom?

Comment: Each `widget` has a main `this.element` property , that has `this.element.onclick = this.togglePanel.bind(this);` on it. This basically binds the widget to its DOM element. I've added this info in the question.